# What is the word for a belief that is nearly universally rejected?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

There is no significant debate over whether or not theft should be legal. There are not pro-theft and anti-theft political groups; basically everyone agrees theft is bad, so that precludes the existence of significant pro-theft groups, and because there are no significant pro-theft groups, there is no need for anti-theft groups.

> Theft from people less wealthy than the thief should be illegal.

Very few people disagree with this opinion. It is *uncontroversial*.

> Theft from people less wealthy than the thief should be legal.

Very few people agree with this. Most people will consider this obviously morally wrong, even if they believe it should be legal to steal in certain cases. It is not a controversial opinion; it is nearly universally rejected.

Because it is not controversial, it seems that it would also be accurate to describe this belief as "uncontroversial," however, I've only heard that word used to refer to something widely accepted.

Is there a single adjective that could go here?

> "Theft from people less wealthy than the thief should be legal" is a _____ opinion.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141463/discussion-on-question-by-someone-what-is-the-word-for-a-belief-that-is-nearly-u).

Comment: So, you are looking for a single word that means outside the [Overton window](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/586259)?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you want to emphasize that people hold this belief in active opposition to a more widely accepted belief, you could use **contrarian**:

> Opposing or rejecting prevailing opinion or established practice; (habitually) going against the popular consensus.

[OED]

Comment: In the same vein, _provocative_ fits the example sentence.

Comment: contrarian has a connotation of going against the mainstream for the sake of being argumentative, not truly holding the position.  I would not generally apply it to, say, flat earth "theory"

Comment: Disagree with @thegreatemu - it doesn't always have that connotation.  A contrarian stock investor is still hoping to make money.

Comment: Wrong. Contrarian is just opposition, and it is not universal: a contrarian is usually a person or a group, not the universe. Suicide being "nearly universally rejected" (c.f. main question) people cannot be said to be _contrarian to suicide_. _Contrarian to suicide_ would imply a group or a person _contrary_ to a majority in favor of suicide.

Answer (score 43):

If you want to emphasize that there might be people who think it, but no one else believes them, then you might use **fringe**.

> 3
> a: something that is marginal, additional, or secondary to some activity, process, or subject
>
> b: : a group with marginal or extremist views

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fringe)

> "Theft should be legal" is a fringe statement.

Comment: The thing with "fringe" is that although it does imply that very few people agree with the statement, it also implies that a small number of people **do** agree with it.  The latter part might not be wanted.

Comment: @JohnBollinger:  The title does say *nearly* universally rejected, so I think that nuance fits within the brief.

Comment: I like fringe as well, it's probably the most polite description I can think of to describe NAMBLA; an organization that wants to legalize activities almost universally regarded as abhorrent in the US.

Answer (score 25):

Maybe *[**heretical**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/heretical)*?

While the primary connotation of the word (think, heresy) is religious, it has another definition, not as common, that **refers to an idea or view that's contrary to mainstream or conventional beliefs** and opinions.

Also consider:

> **heterodox,** *adj*.: holding unorthodox opinions or doctrines  ([Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/heterodox))

(A heretical idea is more controversial than a heterodox one; heretical is a stronger word)

> **iconoclastic,** *adj.*:  a person who attacks settled beliefs or institutions ([Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/iconoclastic))

(A somewhat different meaning; it doesn't fit your example and refers to the person rather than the belief, but it's related enough that I thought it should be included)

Finally, there's the word *radical*, which doesn't quite work here; that thievery should be condoned is not necessarily a 'radical' idea, but the word could possibly be used in a different, fitting context:

> **radical,** *adj.*:
> 1] very different from the usual or traditional, extreme
> 2] favoring extreme changes in existing views, habits, conditions, or institutions ([Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/radical))

Comment: I don't think *heretical* is helpful. Heresy can be nearly universally accepted but that doesn't mean it's right. Or: something can be nearly universally rejected but still be true.

Comment: What do you mean by "radical" "refer[ing] to a more positive belief"? I've only heard it used with a negative connotation.

Comment: @Someone, I guess I'm kind of cherrypicking the supporting example here, but Cambridge Dictionary's entry for 'radical,' under the expanded examples section, offers 'This is a desperate situation which requires a truly radical solution.' But you're right! I may have been thinking about other usages of radical when I wrote that sentence. I'll change it.

Comment: Considering that most people accept that the earth is round, saying that it is cubic is not an _heretical_ idea, it is just _fallacious_.

Answer (score 24):

Perhaps *unorthodox*. This adjective can be used to define people and their behaviour in an individual level, and abstract things like ideas/beliefs/opinions in a more universal level.

> (of behavior, ideas, or methods) different from what is usual or expected - [*Cambridge*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unorthodox)

*Unorthodox* differs from the adjective *unconventional* which is a bit less strong in connotation than *unorthodox*; and *unorthodox* works better for ideas that go against more serious moral norms like not stealing. *Unconventional* works better for things that deviate from cultural norms like how to dress, speak, act and it can define a lifestyle.

Comment: I'm not sure how strong "unorthodox" is - it's often used of things like boxing stances and other things which are non-standard but not necessarily shocking or unheard-of. The alternative answers like "heretical" are definitely stonger.

Comment: Stronger than _unconventional_. However, people can decide to use it with milder connotations.

Answer (score 16):

They might be **marginal**, one definition of which ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/marginal)) is:

> excluded from or existing outside the mainstream of society, a group, or a school of thought

This is one of the most neutral ways to say that.

Some relatively positive ways to say this are **unconventional**, **dissenting** (although I was beaten to that one) and even **brave**.

Some slang terms with a strongly negative connotation are **crank** (from a German word meaning “sick”), **crackpot** (someone with a serious brain injury), **nuts/nutty/nutso** (One theory is that this also being a slang term for testes led to the Bowdlerization *nertz*, which became *nerds*.) or if there are several of them, **cultish**.

Comment: Crackpot... a fugazi? Fuhgeddaboudit, +1.

Comment: Ah, _marginal_ is perfect, but (appropriately) just out of reach of my mind.  Thanks for suggesting that one!  (And _brave_ reminds me of classic British TV sitcom; "_A quite brave statement, Minister...._"

Comment: @TobySpeight And like I said, I thought *dissenting* was a great one, and then only realized later ....

Comment: [Orwell was fond of the word crank](https://www.cabinetmagazine.org/issues/20/laity.php) to refer to the sort of person who has a sense of superiority in their counter-cultural beliefs, with the superiority coming in part because their beliefs were so unpopular.

Answer (score 11):

We might call this a **[dissenting](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dissenting)** view (Wiktionary):

> **dissenting** (*comparative* **more dissenting**, *superlative* **most dissenting**)
>
> Showing a strongly different opinion, belief, or viewpoint.

Answer (score 11):

You can call it an **[eccentric](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eccentric)** view. (Merriam-Webster: "deviating from conventional or accepted usage or conduct especially in odd or whimsical ways"; "deviating from an established or usual pattern or style")

Or an **[idiosyncratic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/idiosyncrasy)** statement. (Merriam-Webster: idiosyncrasy: "a peculiarity of constitution or temperament : an individualizing characteristic or quality")

Answer (score 8):

For a word that means "nearly universally rejected," try . . .

> **indefensible**, *adj.*
> **2.** Incapable of being defended in argument, maintained, or vindicated; unjustifiable, inexcusable.
>  <sub>Source: [Oxford English
> Dictionary](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

> *"Theft should be legal" is an indefensible statement.*

Comment: I don’t think that implies that a view *is* nearly-universally-rejected, only that it *ought to* be. For example, [“Alcohol-Related Hazing Common, Indefensible.”](https://thegreyhound.org/site/alcohol-related-hazing-common-indefensible/)

Comment: @Davislor — If no one is willing or able to defend the statement, it has been rejected.

Comment: That’s not how it’s used, though. A few more examples: “What is the most intellectually indefensible and socially harmful belief to gain widespread currency in your industry?” (Bryan Caplan), “there is a widespread ignorance [...]. It is not, I repeat, that the thinkers, the writers and the leaders of popular thought, in whatever media, have for the most part studied [...] and rejected it as unhistoric, impractical and outdated. It is simply that they have not studied it at all! I believe their attitude of almost total ignorance to be quite indefensible, [...]” (J.B. Phillips)

Comment: ‘Indefensible’ means that it _cannot_ be defended. If it could be defended, but _isn't_ (which is what the question is asking), then it's not indefensible, but merely ‘undefended’.

Comment: “Why Plagiarizing Sermons is Popular, But Biblically Indefensible”, a [paper](https://www.mdpi.com/2227-7102/8/2/72) that opens with,“This paper describes two myths that circulate widely about the potential of students with Learning Disabilities to learn mathematics” and concludes, “Finally, I assert that these myths are indefensible.”

Comment: @gidds That’s not how the word is actually used, though. People frequently say *indefensible* when they mean that there is no **sound** or **correct** defense. There are many, many, many examples of people calling a view both “indefensible” and “common,” “widespread,” “widely-held,” etc. The ones I’ve cited are just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: Also, even if somebody somehow thinks that we can use words correctly by looking up the definition in a dictionary and applying it literally, it is possible for some position to be widely assumed or practiced without anyone actually defending it.

Comment: This is the equivalent of saying that “militarily indefensible” means that a position is completely unoccupied, rather than that an attack on that position would surely succeed. A military historian could very well write, “The entire army was deployed in an indefensible position,” and the argument that an “indefensible” position “cannot be defended,” ergo no one must be in such a position or they would need to defend it, would be wrong. At least about English word usage.

Comment: @Davislor — So are you saying that because alcohol-related hazing is common,  there are plenty of proponents of alcohol-related hazing?

Comment: @TinfoilHat Calling it “indefensible” does not imply that there are or that there are not such people, because “indefensible” means “Anyone who defends this would be wrong,” not “No one ever attempts to defend this at all.” The Collins English Dictionary has a better definition in this case, which reflects that more clearly. In any case, this is why I listed multiple examples.

Comment: @Davislor We don't seem to be disagreeing over very much :-) Perhaps I should have said that ‘indefensible’ is used for views that cannot be _correctly_ (or perhaps reasonably) defended — but _not_ (as this answer claims) that few or no people even _try_ to defend them. For the latter, I still think ‘undefended’ would be more accurate.

Comment: @gidds Ah, okay. Sorry if I misunderstood you. I think the upshot is, the word doesn’t mean what the OP wants to convey.

Answer (score 8):

One possibility I haven't seen yet is **anathema**.

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anathema) has

> someone or something intensely disliked or loathed —usually used as a predicate nominative

With example use of *"this notion was anathema to most of his countrymen."*
—Stephen Jay Gould.

You could get away with it as a single word in contexts where it is implied exactly *who* the idea is anathema *to*. It has the downside that it can only be used when the statement is somewhat emotively opposed, rather than just being incontrovertibly but blandly considered to be false.

Answer (score 5):

Another suggestion would be [**taboo**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/taboo):

> Something that is avoided or forbidden for religious or social reasons

Comment: Taboo carries baggage about why the thing is rejected. It may even imply that it might be accepted in a different culture. It happens to fit with the specific example of theft, but not with other things that otherwise fit OP's descript. "2+2 = 5" is nearly universally rejected, but it isn't taboo.

Answer (score 3):

A few words that fit into the statement asking about an adjective could be [**outlandish**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outlandish), [**pretentious**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pretentious), [**unbelievable**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unbelievable), or [**dubious**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dubious).

I've referenced and quoted the sources below that helped me draw this conclusion. I believe these also fit into the "universally rejected" meaning too.

> #### Outlandish
>
> strikingly out of the ordinary : [BIZARRE](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bizarre)
>
> exceeding proper or reasonable limits or standards
>
> [Source](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outlandish)

---

> #### Pretentious
>
> making usually unjustified or excessive claims (as of value or standing)
>
> expressive of affected, unwarranted, or exaggerated importance, worth, or stature
>
> [Source](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pretentious)

---

> #### Unbelievable
>
> too improbable for belief
>
> also : of such a superlative degree as to be hard to believe
>
> [Source](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unbelievable)

---

> #### Dubious
>
> unsettled in opinion : DOUBTFUL
>
> giving rise to uncertainty: such as: of doubtful promise or outcome
>
> questionable or suspect as to true nature or quality
>
> [Source](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dubious)

Comment: Dubious is an interesting one. It means doubtful or likely to fail, but a lot of people could hold a dubious position. The most famous line that uses it would be Milton’s “in dubious battle on the plains of Heav’n,” where all the fallen angels were fighting on the losing side. That’s a very poetic usage, but I think it’s basically still how we use the word today.

Comment: Outlandish works fine, I think! Great one.  Nefarious means something different.

Answer (score 3):

While they are phrases rather than words, I think the best things to fill in your blank would be close to what you started with. Namely, I would use "generally rejected" or if you wanted to emphasize how thoroughly the opposing view predominated, consider just using your original "nearly universally rejected".

> "Theft should be legal" is a generally rejected statement.

There are many things in English that never develop a single word to describe them because a short phrase suffices. I believe this is one of those cases.

I also think, that as mentioned in R.M.'s answer, "fringe" comes very close to your meaning if you really want a single word, but I believe "generally rejected" conveys exactly what you are getting at and does so without any of the baggage and implications that some of the other words suggested carry.

---

As a tangent, but a closely related one, I happen to be a lawyer in Nevada. I agree that almost no one would say that theft should be legal. But there can be considerable argument over exactly what constitutes theft or whether a specific theft may have been sufficiently justified as to take it out of the realm of being a crime. Some of these distinctions can have significant ramifications in the law.

Answer (score 2):

Theft should be legal is an **unacceptable** opinion.

---

I think it's a good word because:

1. Contrarian, is probably justified as the top answer, but I think it is normally used to describe a person.  Contrarians whole contrarian opinions, which is a redundant way to say contrarians also hold unacceptable opinions.
2. Fringe, marginal, crackpot, nutty, fantasy and idiosyncratic seem like the beginning of  an *ad hominem* argument, which ought to be avoided.
3. Provocative, radical, dissenting, contentious and unconventional are more applicable in court or politics, but aren't universally applicable.
4. Dubious, nonsensical, irrational, spurious and unbelievable make you doubt the sanity of the holder of the belief and are the beginning of [the genetic fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_fallacy)
5. Unorthodox, heretical, anathema, iconoclastic, cultish and taboo are more dogmatic. If the example was a purely religious one, that would fit but "thou shalt not steal" is a self-evident truth.

Unacceptable is just a straightforward way to say, something is generally not accepted, but it's not impossible to comprehend a person accepting of it.

Answer (score 2):

## [Non-starter](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonstarter%5D)

(informal) a person, plan, or idea that has no chance of succeeding or being effective.  "as a business proposition it's a nonstarter"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to emphasise that this is universally rejected because it doesn't make any sense, you could easily use the word **[irrational](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irrational)**:

> not governed by or according to reason

Note that this is distinct from beliefs that may have been plausible based on limited initial evidence, but where further evidence shifts the consensus against them.  For example, belief in the existence of phlogiston in the 17th century was not irrational, even though it was universally rejected in the 18th century.

Of course, do be aware that this represents a value judgement not only on the belief but also on people who believe it.  This would not be an appropriate word if you want to debate people with this belief in good faith.

Comment: I don’t think this implies that a view is rare. Popular views are often called irrational, for example, [“What are some of the most common, but still irrational things people believe about money?”](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-of-the-most-common-but-still-irrational-things-people-believe-about-money?share=1)

Comment: @Davislor You're confusing views/opinions with behaviour. Humans are very bad at rational behaviour, as that list describes. But the title is flat wrong, because no human believes that any of those things *are* good to do. They're things we all categorically know are bad, in the same way as the OP asks, but we do them anyway. Sometimes because it seems the best of different bad options, and sometimes because it's just easier than making proper rational decisions. (And yes, I do include myself! :)

Comment: Okay, so would you agree that people often describe widely-held *beliefs* that they know many other people will argue are correct as “irrational,” too? For example, would you agree that this is very common on all sides of arguments over religion and atheism? Whether or not you believe this to be the wrong way to use the word, as you felt my first example used the word wrong, that is in fact how the word is commonly used?

Answer (score 1):

There are two main approaches to this question, what one might term *factual* and *implicational* (if such a word exists). Most of the answers have been in the latter category — a belief that is held by few people is controversial, heretic, fantastic, contrarian etc. I find all of these unsatisfactory because none is universal — each only applies in particular circumstances and does not necessarily imply near-universal rejection.

If the factual approach is taken, we are forced to consider the like of

> “Theft should be legal” is a **minority** opinion.

or

> “Theft should be legal” is a **rare** opinion.

These may seem rather feeble, as what they lack is an indication of the extreme infrequency with which the opinion is held. I do not know of a single word that has this implication (of for the -issimo of Italian!), and so if I had to use an adjective I would qualify it with an adverb:

> “Theft should be legal” is a **extreme minority** opinion.

or

> “Theft should be legal” is an **extremely rare** opinion.

The latter has the advantage of not using a noun as an adjective.

Comment: Although rare is right in the meaning "hard to find, not common" , the word comes with a connotation of "good/excellent".

Comment: @MartialP — not in this context, any more than its meaning of lightly cooked.

Answer (score 1):

I would said it is a **niche** opinion.

"Niche" both highlights that it's believed by
only «a tiny segment of the population», but also suggest that said segment of population have their specific reasons (here, moral set or beliefs) that leads them to have such opinion that majority would simply disregard.

Another word for that could be "marginal".

Answer (score 1):

## [Fallacious](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/fallacious)

> #### Synonyms
>
> - erroneous.
> - false.
> - incorrect.
> - untrue
> - wrong
>
> #### Examples of Usage
>
> ---
>
> > The information on the website is ***fallacious***
>
> ---
>
> > No one could explain how the ***fallacious*** information had gotten into the report.

Answer (score 1):

A **folly**.

Though follies are often associated with some alleged perception which is explained by the folly.

Comment: It doesn't really fit the sample sentence from the question though.

Comment: . . . folliful . . . ?

Comment: That's a judgement, that also tell nothing about how little that belief is spread. So it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

*discredited*

/diˈskredədəd/

adjective

brought into disrepute; having lost respect or credibility.

"a discredited system"

Answer (score 0):

What about nonsense or [nonsensical](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonsense)?

> language, conduct, or an idea that is absurd or contrary to good sense

Calling an idea nonsensical would imply that you believe no reasonable person would think of it.  Some fun synonyms are balderdash, bunk, claptrap, and gibberish.

Comment: I don't think that's the word. Nonsense is more used in ideas that are illogical or non-sensical on its face. Whereas something can make sense on a superficial level but few agree with it given a broader view on the matter

Comment: I mean... "'Theft should be legal is a nonsensical' statement" totally makes sense. But the OP seems to think that that statement isn't quite such a nonsense..

Comment: I don’t think “nonsensical” carries the implication that a view is not widely held. Urban Dictionary even has [Common Nonsense](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Common%20Nonsense) for the exact opposite. Or, for example, “How To Reverse The Widespread, Nonsensical Principles Of Utopianism.”

Answer (score 0):

If an idea or suggestion is very far off mainstream it may be a **fantasy** or even border on the **delusional**. As in "the suggestion to stop prosecuting theft borders on the delusional", because in the opinion of the speaker here it is common knowledge that human nature makes law enforcement necessary. Everybody who thinks otherwise has lost their touch with reality.

Calling something a *fantasy* is less of an *ad hominem* argument because it focuses on the viability of an idea rather than on the proponent's state of mind. For example, ideas to defund the police could be called fantasies at least in conservative circles because there is no way the suggestion could find a majority, and even if it did, it would not be viable.

"Delusional" is probably fitting best for conspiracy theories like [pizzagate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pizzagate_conspiracy_theory). It implies that the idea's absurdity is so obvious and requires so much mental contortion that it does not merit a detailed answer.

Comment: Don't want to bring politic in that, but your exemple is terrible since it have been proved true. The pizzagate was about a club of million/billionaires having pedo activities, wich have been mediumly spread through the population (enough to not consider it marginal) and finally proven true with the Epstein Case, despite not involving one exact pizzeria that was just an irrelevant detail of the story.

Comment: @MartialP Good example, actually. Between the Epstein case and Pizzagate lies the line separating sanity and delusion. I understand that on occasion, like with the Catholic abuse scandals, that line becomes blurry (i.e., most sane people that are not insiders would have rejected the idea of systemic abuse and cover-ups by the church leadership until just a few years ago). But not in most other cases, including Pizzagate.

Comment: @MartialP And then there is always the [Gustl Mollath case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gustl_Mollath) where a psychiatrist [famously said](https://www.zeit.de/gesellschaft/zeitgeschehen/2013-06/psychiatrie-mollath-krankheit-unterbringung-interview-henning-sass/komplettansicht) (translation from me): "There is some truth to that story but the ideas based on it may still be pathological, removed from reality and excessive." As in the famous adage "that I'm crazy doesn't mean I'm not being followed."

Answer (score -2):

If your audience is familiar with logical terms, you might be able to use:

## [Contradiction](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/contradiction):

> someone or something with qualities or features that seem to conflict with one another

In logic, a *contradiction* is the opposite of a *tautology* (a statement that is always true.)  That is a *contradiction* is a statement is always false.  For example:

"That theft should be legal is essentially a logical *contradiction*."

Comment: As an opinion, what does it contradict? What about other positions that nobody supports? Is there a contradiction in "grocery shoppers should be required to wear reflective clothing for visibility"?

Comment: @Laurel I think you might be thinking of the general usage of the word.  A logical contraction is in conflict with itself.  The idea of theft being legal would.  The fundamental concept of theft is that it is a crime.  A legal crime is a logical contradiction.  If it were legal, theft wouldn't be a crime, and therefore it can't be theft, it's just 'taking'.

Comment: Regardless of whether this particular statement is self-contradictory, the term "contradiction" does not at all carry the meaning of "nearly universally rejected" that the question is asking about.

Comment: @V2Blast How many people do you know that would not reject a logical contradiction?

Comment: @JimmyJames: It's not about whether people would end up rejecting a contradictory statement/belief; it's about the fact that "nearly universally rejected" is just not what "contradiction" means.

Comment: @V2Blast I disagree.  That's a precisely one of the connotations of a logical contradictions.  They should be completely universally rejected however some people don't seem to grasp the concept.

Comment: The example statement from the OP, "Theft should be legal." is also not a contradiction, as the act of theft still exists in the absence of any legal framework, as when a chimp steals its partner's banana.

Comment: @DewiMorgan The definition of theft inherently implies a crime.  A chimp can take another chimp's banana.  You are free to call it a theft if you perceive it as a crime, perhaps under 'natural law'.  It' similar to the difference between the words 'murder' and 'kill'.  It's also the case that words are often used in different ways in different contexts.  For example, we could use the concept of 'logical contradiction' metaphorically.  There's nothing about the English language that prevents that.